# How to use units in delphi project group

Tags: delphi, group-project

I have a group of projects with 3 projects (standAlone, ISAPI, module for apache), until now they all have the same file.pas and when modifying code and compiling the .exe, the .dll and .so are updated.

I want to add another unit (.pas file) to better organize classes and make it easier to navigate through the project code.

My question is, should I add the new file.pas to the three projects or only to the standAlone?
(use RAD Studio 10.2)

Comment: Surely you add it to each project that uses it

Comment: ISTM that that is a matter of opinion. I rather add every unit to all projects, but that is not really necessary.

Comment: Indeed, this is purely a matter of preference. You could A) Explicitly add the unit to your project, B) Keep the unit in the same directory as your project and it should find it when used, C) Put the unit in the project's search path, or D) Put the unit in the IDE's search/library path. They all accomplish the same thing: allowing you to use the unit in your project. There are far too many different variables involved when one needs to decide which options to choose, and many of those variables are based on opinion.